# QListWidget show item number near text

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget

Is there any simple way to add the row number (start = 1) left the item text?

I know how can i do it manually, but then if i delete or reorder the items i should change that numbers.

So why i am asking, for a simple way.

I search in documentation, but i don't found something for that.
Also Qt Designer hasn't something about.

I have a QListWidget like this in the image (the right frame shows details of selected item)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a delegate:

```
class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.text = f"{index.row() + 1}. {option.text}"
```

```
delegate = Delegate(listWidget)
listWidget.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```